# Room Persistence Migration Indices

Tags: android, migration, android-room

Good evening.
I am having trouble adding indices to my entity.. I wrote a migration but it keeps saying my sql statement is wrong... can anybody help me, pls?

here's my entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "RAuditRemarksRecord",
        indices = [Index(name = "index_RAuditRemarksRecord_sheet_id",
                value = ["sheetId"],
                unique = true)])
data class RAuditRemarksRecord(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
                               var id: Long? = null,
                               var sheetId: String = "",
                               var remarks: String = "",
                               var isDraft: Boolean = false)
```

and here is my migration sql statement

```
database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX index_RAuditRemarksRecord_sheet_id " +
                    "ON  RAuditRemarksRecord(sheetId)")
```

error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.zynappse.alfamart.storeauditv2/databases/app_db
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1662)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.execSQL(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:242)
        at com.zynappse.alfamart.storeauditv2.data.DatabaseManager$MIGRATION_3_4$1.migrate(DatabaseHelper.kt:47)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:85)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:133)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:299)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:194)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:233)
        at com.zynappse.alfamart.storeauditv2.data.dao.SyncStatusDao_Impl$5.compute(SyncStatusDao_Impl.java:311)
        at com.zynappse.alfamart.storeauditv2.data.dao.SyncStatusDao_Impl$5.compute(SyncStatusDao_Impl.java:297)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:100)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

any help would be great. Thank you :)

ps. I already incremented my version (from 3 to 4) :)